# File Server performance with simultaneous read/write operation

Tags: windows-server-2008, performance, filesystems, network-share

I have a WORKGROUP network with 50+ devices, all the computers can access a Windows Server 2008 R2 server which hosts all the media in the network. When one or some of the users are copying files from the server the access to server becomes severely slow, that is, other users can barely browse any of the media on the server.
How can I solve this problem? Is there a specific solution to it? Does the network type DOMAIN/WORKGROUP matter?

Thank you in advance..

Comment: To solve the problem, you need to find the bottleneck. Most likely you need to upgrade your server or network. But you didn’t provide any of those hardware details. This is not a software fix.

Comment: I am not sure where the bottleneck is really. But I think it is mostly the storage since I am using kinda slow Hard drives 5000/7200 RPM. But why copying one file makes the whole thing slow?

Comment: How are those hard drives configured into filesystem(s) and presented to the client machines?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, they are presented as a network share folder.

Comment: OK, that's half of what I asked.  How many disk(s) are there?  How are they grouped into RAID arrays, if any?  What kind of disk controller(s) are being used?  What kind of RAID controllers, if any?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, Only one disk. Would RAID 1 or RAID 5 solve the performance problem? It seems to me that it might help the performance but not that much.